# Convert inputted time duration to minutes:seconds

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

I'm working on [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g3likuM4iN3PT0tCon5rEdF8gvOcfaGG1oHtQjOQFGg/edit?usp=sharing), and I wish to convert the data in columns C, D, and E from hours and minutes to minutes and seconds.

For example, an inputted `7:08` turned into `07:08:00.000` (hours and minutes, no seconds) when it should be something like `00:07:08.000` instead (minutes and seconds, no hours).

Is there a way to change how Google Sheets to input time by default so that a duration inputted as `mm:ss` is automatically turned into `mm:ss`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- if the custom time format is set to **`mm:ss`** you need to input **7min & 8sec** as **`0:7:8`**
- otherwise you need to use a formula and +1 column to convert it into a plausible format

  - **`=TEXT(TIME(, HOUR(C2), MINUTE(C2)), "m:ss")`** (output is text)
  - **`=VALUE(TEXT(TIME(, HOUR(C2), MINUTE(C2)), "m:ss"))`** (needs to be custom formated)
  - **`=TIMEVALUE(TEXT(TIME(, HOUR(C2), MINUTE(C2)), "m:ss"))`** (works best)